# How to get value datapicker in react toobox custom?

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

How can I get the value of datapicker in react toobox?
I am using custom components.

I am using 2 components first one is called `InputDateCustom.js` with the code below:

```js
import DatePicker from 'react-toolbox/lib/date_picker/DatePicker';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const datetime = new Date(2015, 10, 16);
datetime.setHours(17);
datetime.setMinutes(28);
    
export default  class InputDateCustomizado extends Component{
    state = {date2: datetime};

    handleChange = (item, value) => {
        console.log(item+" - "+value)
        this.setState({...this.state, [item]: value});
    };

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
             <DatePicker
                label={this.props.label}
                locale={localeExample}                
                name={this.props.name}
                required={this.props.required}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'date1')}
                value={this.state.date1}
             />
         </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Another component is called `Cadastro.js` that contains the following logic:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {msg: '', fim_vigencia:'', nome:''}
    this.setNome = this.setNome.bind(this)
    this.setFimVigencia  = this.setFimVigencia.bind(this)
}
   
setFimVigencia(evento){
  console.log("date")
   this.setState({fim_vigencia:evento.target.value});
}

InputDateCustomizado
    id="fim_vigencia" 
    label="Fim"
    name="fim_vigencia" 
    value    = {this.state.fim_vigencia}
    onSubmit = {this.setFimVigencia}
/>
```

Comment: so.... what's the problem? Need a bit more than just a code snippet

Comment: There is no problem, I would just like to get the value in another component

Comment: Ah the edits make it clear

Comment: Do you have any idea to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value in an onChange event or using the `value` prop. Doc examples: http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/date_picker

`<DatePicker label='Birthdate' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'date1')} value={this.state.date1} />`

You can get access to the value in the `handleChange` event allowing you to update your state with the currently selected date.

EDIT: Ah okay I think I understand what you are asking now. You have wrapped `DatePicker` with your own component and now you want to get the `DatePicker` value through the `Cadastro.js` component.

You need to create a method in the `Cadastro.js` that accepts state changes from the `InputDateCustomizado` component and then pass that function as a prop to the `InputDateCustomizado` component. In the `InputDateCustomizado` when the state changes, call the passed in function and it should update the state in the parent component. Then you will always have the datepicker value in the parent component.

It looks like you are almost there. You need to add an `updateState` function to the `Cadastro.js` component. In the `InputDateCustomizado` component `handleChange` event, you need to call `this.props.updateState` and pass in the new value.

In `Cadastro.js`

```
updateState = (data) => {
    this.setState({
        date: data.data //set your state here to the date
    })
}
```

In `InputDateCustomizado`

```
    handleChange = (item, value) => {
        console.log(item+" - "+value)
        this.setState({...this.state, [item]: value});
        this.props.updateState(this.state);
    };
```

Comment: INputDateCUstomizado. js https://github.com/luizcarlospedrosogomes/pontua/blob/master/pontua-cliente-react/src/componentes/InputDateCustomizado.js           cadastro.js: https://github.com/luizcarlospedrosogomes/pontua/blob/master/pontua-cliente-react/src/representante/CadastrarPromocao.js  resolved